# Accessing Element Object Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.exampleObj = function(options) {

      var defaults = [
          label: "example",
          value: false
      ];

      options = $.extend(defaults, options);

      this.test = true;
    }
})($);
```

Once I create a new one

```
$('.div-custom').exampleObj();
```

How would I access 'test' on the console by entering

```
$('.div-custom');
```

Result should return

```
true
```

Or if I wanted to change 'test' to false how would I do that?

```
this.test = false;
```

Thanks

Comment: `$('.jwSelect').jwSelect()`?

Comment: Your script has a syntax error. Please fix it.

Comment: `(new $.fn.jwSelect).test` should do.